# How to extract an image src from a zip file using javascript and then display it to the web page

Tags: javascript, unzip

I have a webpage where I drop the zip file which extracts the files. how to get the file and use it as img src. I'm getting 'undefined' **imgurl1** value

```
    let url1 = "IM/" + DIALOG_BACKGROUND_IMAGE ;
        try {
              JSZip.loadAsync(newFile).then(function (zip) {
                   for (var name in zip.files) {
                       if (name === url1) {
                           return  zipFiles.file(name).async('blob');
                       }
                   }
              return zip.file("").async("string");
              }).then(function success(blob) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
                    reader.onloadend = function() {
                    imgurl1 = reader.result;     
                 }
                 puttingData(data, imgurl1,imgurl1);                    
             }, function error(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                 });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
```

Comment: It looks like the data you are after is only available once reader.onloadend has triggered.  Have you tried putting `puttingData(data, imgurl1,imgurl1);` inside the reader.onloadend function?

Comment: Ok after putting it to inside the reader.onloadend function value changed to 
imgurl1: data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBO... so on when i clicked on that link it's downloaded but that image didn't had any type or extension when I changed it to jpg then it opened.. am I missing something?

Comment: If you're asking about the mime type of the blob, check https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/626

Comment: Issue solved Thank you James. just added this line before reading blob : `const zipEntryFile = new File([blob], zipEntry.name, { type: 'Image/jpeg' });`